# October CMS проблема импорта csv

Tags: laravel, october, octobercms

Создал плагин с помощью Builder (там же создал таблицу в БД). Для проверки импорта и экспорта создал по докам https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/import-export контроллер, представление и модуль
 Экспорт работает как часы в отличии от импорта. Импорт выводит ошибки "Mass assignment failed for Model attribute 'attribute_name'"

Контроллер

```
<?php namespace Name\Holodilnik\Controllers;

use Backend\Classes\Controller;
use BackendMenu;

class Cargo extends Controller
{
    public $implement = [ 'Backend\Behaviors\ListController',
        'Backend\Behaviors\FormController',
        'Backend.Behaviors.ImportExportController'];

    public $listConfig = 'config_list.yaml';
    public $formConfig = 'config_form.yaml';
    public $importExportConfig = 'config_import_export.yaml';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        BackendMenu::setContext('Name.Holodilnik', 'menu');
    }
}
```

Модуль

```
<?php namespace Name\Holodilnik\Models;

use Backend\Models\ImportModel;
use System\Models\File;
use Name\Holodilnik\Models\Cargo;


class CargoImportModel extends ImportModel
{
    public $table = 'name_holodilnik_cargo';

    protected $guarded = [];

    public $rules = [];


    public function importData($results, $sessionKey = null)
    {
        foreach ($results as $row => $data)
        {




            try {
                $cargo = new Cargo();
                $cargo->fill($data);



                $cargo->save();

                if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
                    $this->logUpdated();
                } else {
                    $this->logCreated();
                }



            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $this->logError($row, $ex->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Подскажите куда копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В основном модуле нужно добавить

```php
protected $fillable = [ 'attribute_name'];
```